# How to represent the timeline of events (date-times) in R

Tags: r, datetime, ggplot2

I have a data.frame with a date-time-column, like

```
 D = data.frame(time = c("2007-06-22","2007-05-22","2007-05-23"))
 D$time <- strptime(D$time, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
 class(D$time)
"POSIXlt" "POSIXt"
```

I would like to create a plot with an additional neutral timeline on the x-axis, say, for year 2007, ticks/units should be month. So just a "histogram" of dates.

I tried `hist(D$time, breaks = "days")` but it just returns errors.

Otherwise dates could be plotted for the given time-interval (say year 2007) for each single date, on a metric scale. So something like "geom_jitter".

I tried `ggplot(D$time)` but it can't handle the POSIXlt/POSIXt class.

I am looking for an easy straightforward way to plot my time events on within a given interval. Thank you so much.

Comment: Can you post what exactly must be the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ggplot2` and `scales` to achieve this:

```
library(gglot2)
library(scales)
```

First create a ggplot with `data = D` and `time` as you x aesthetic. Add a `geom_bar()` (i.e. the bars) and change the x axis to show only the month and set specific limits (in this case first and last day of 2007):

```
ggplot(data = D, aes(x = time)) + geom_bar() + 
  scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%b"),
               limits = c(as.Date('2007-01-01'), as.Date('2007-12-31')))
```

Which returns:

[image: ggplot_output]

If you want to show the events per month, you could use `lubridate` and `dplyr`, and `ggplot2`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)

D = data.frame(time = c("2007-06-22","2007-05-22","2007-05-23"))
```

In this case you get the abbreviated month of the date:

```
D2 <- D
D2$month <- month(D$time, label = TRUE)
```

You can group by month and count the number of events:

```
D2 <- D2 %>% 
  group_by(month) %>%
  summarise(n = n())
```

Add the missing months (if any) to your dataframe with `n = 0`:

```
D2 <- rbind(D2, 
            data.frame(month = levels(D2$month)[!(levels(D2$month) %in% D2$month)],
                       n = 0))
```

Plot the new data (Note: use `stat = 'identity'` in `geom_bar()` since you explicitly pass the count in the `y` aesthetic:):

```
ggplot(data = D2, aes(x = month, y = n)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
```

Which returns:

[image: output2]

Option number 3:

A more flexible approach using many years:

```
D = data.frame(time = c("2006-05-16", "2007-06-22","2007-05-22","2007-05-23"))
```

(Note: One date in different year added)

Create an additional `year` column:

```
D3 <- D
D3$month <- month(D$time, label = TRUE)
D3$year <- year(D$time)
```

Group by `month` and `year`:

```
D3 <- D3 %>% 
  group_by(year, month) %>%
  summarise(n = n())
```

Find the missing months per year:

```
missing <- do.call("rbind", 
                   lapply(unique(D3$year), function(y) {
                     data.frame(year = y,
                                month = levels(D3[D3$year == y, ]$month)[!(levels(D3[D3$year == y, ]$month) %in% D3[D3$year == y, ]$month)],
                                n = 0)


                   }))
```

Combine `D3` and `missing`:

```
all <- rbind(as.data.frame(D3), missing)
```

Create new visualisation:

```
ggplot(data = all, aes(x = month, y = n, group = factor(year), fill = factor(year))) + 
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = 'identity')
```

Which looks like this:

[image: ggplot_3]

Comment: Ok Ilike the result, but it's a little workaround and I'm not that flexible on others design versions. If I get new years and want to plot it by years I always have to define new colomn first, right? Is there a way to handle the one-variable time-case directly? Regards